# Dynamize a static jquery function where a div of class "slider" has a number at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, dynamic, integer

I'm currently facing a problem with a jQuery function. The task of the function is to detect if the URL has a specific string in it, and then do a specific task. This is the code:

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.search('slick0') > -1) {
  $('.accordion #slider0 dt').addClass('open').removeClass('closed');
  $($slider).slick('setPosition'); 
}
```

The part `slider0` and `slick0` should be any integer.

So the function should search for `slickN`, where `N` is the integer, and then do the actions on `.accordion #sliderN dt`, as in the function above.

I've tried the following code, but it doesn't work at all, and I haven't had any luck trying or even finding different ways to a solution, for which me being not a native speaker may be the cause, but I just can't seem to find the right direction.

This is my alternative which does not work at all:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var sliderNumber = $.isNumeric;
if (url.search('slick'+sliderNumber) > -1) {
  $('.accordion #slider'+sliderNumber 'dt').addClass('open').removeClass('closed');
  $($slider).slick('setPosition'); 
}
```

Can anyone help me or point me into the right direction? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `/slider\d/.test(url)`

Comment: I am not fully understanding your problem. Your URL contains a string of which you do not know the integer part? Where is that string, can you give an example of such an url and try to describe a bit more what exactly your intention is?

Comment: @user3154108 Thank you for your comment. The point of the function being dynamic is that the client can add new sliders and content without always adding a new function. The URL would look like this: http://www.website.de/subpage/another-subpage.html?slick0=4. This means the **first** slider and it's **fifth** slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression, as K102 suggested in his comment.

```
var url = 'http://testurl_with_slider0_in_it'
var matches = url.match(/slider[\d]{1,}/);

if (matches) {
    $('.accordion #' + matches[0] + ' dt').addClass('open').removeClass('closed');
    $($slider).slick('setPosition');
} else {
    console.log('No match');
}
```

`url.match(/slider[\d]{1,}/)` will match the word 'slider' with at least one following digit.

To limit the amount of digits to, for example 3, simply modify `{1,}` to `{1,3}`

Comment: Thank you, this might actually be a really sufficient approach! Do I need to have a variable url for every subpage where I have a slider in? Or is it possible to check if theres a slider on the page and then do stuff with the current URL. I'll try to fiddle around and tell you how it worked out, thank you! @DKSan

Comment: Try `if ( $('.slider').length ) { 
  //Do Stuff 
} else {
  //No Slider;
}` in document ready handler. For this to work your sliders all need the class slider. If you already have another class that identifies them use this.

Comment: Already got it working, just used var url = window.location.href; Thanks, @DKSan!

Comment: That might be another approach, thanks. Which one is better?